# How to remove Microsoft Account?

Tags: security, azure, microsoft-account

I have an account that I don't use anymore. I would like to remove it in order to test some Microsoft Azure coding features.

The problem is that I can't remove the account.

I navigate to the account profile, click on the "close account" link, it says me that I should cancel the paid services... I have any paid services, so I click OK, but the message goes around and I strart from what I began... I see that people have [similar](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oaccount-ocloseacc/unable-to-delete-windows-live-id-account/ad01a2b6-da02-4eb9-9606-10751c3e7682) problem.

Does anybody know how to deal with?

Comment: I would start with emailing Microsoft customer support.

Comment: there is no such a public "email"...

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/contactus

Comment: Thanks for advising, but not used to phone Microsoft to resolve such a bagatelle...

Comment: Microsoft just released a new Close Account page that should make it easier to close. If you're sure you don't have any other paid services, I believe it lets you force close the account now without the runaround. Check out: https://account.live.com/closeaccount.aspx